# HPA scaling delay

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

We have kubernetes EKS cluster with keda and custom policies to limit scale up like 1 pod per 5 minute.

After some spike where desired capacity calculated as 100 replicas HPA is adding replicas with limited rate (1 pod per 5 minute) but very long time.

How can we control time of reaction of hpa.

[Graph for case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wh2H.png)

[Graph for case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx0aO.png)

Our current config:

```
spec:
  advanced:
    horizontalPodAutoscalerConfig:
      behavior:
        scaleDown:
          policies:
          - periodSeconds: 600
            type: Pods
            value: 1
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 1200
        scaleUp:
          policies:
          - periodSeconds: 1200
            type: Pods
            value: 1
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 10
  minReplicaCount: 1
  pollingInterval: 30
  scaleTargetRef:
    envSourceContainerName: celery
    name: celery
  triggers:
  - metadata:
      queueName: celery
      listLength: "2"
    type: redis
```